# Python: Project version reads properly in venv, but as an installed package, returns "app.exe, version <class 'packaging.version.Version'>" instead

Tags: python, python-3.x, build, argparse, hatch

I am writing a simple python application that's compiled with a hatch build system.
[hatch.pypa.io](https://hatch.pypa.io)

I have properly defined pyproject.toml and I have properly declared version as per documentation here:
[hatch metadata docu](https://hatch.pypa.io/latest/config/metadata/#__tabbed_3_2)

When using argparser and it's `--version` argument, the version such as `1.0.1` gets returned in venv properly, but once it's installled as a global package, with:
`pip install -e .`

Then called using commandline entrypoint, then the version is instead:

`app.exe, version <class 'packaging.version.Version'>`

I have tried various solutions for this such as:

```
versionParsed = importlib.metadata.version('app_name')
```

```
from pkg_resources import get_distribution
versionParsed = get_distribution('app name')
```

But despite those 2 approaches, one new the other old, the situation is the same, outside of venv, the version returned isn't numerical, but instead:

`app.exe, version <class 'packaging.version.Version'>`

The way I defined argparser to get version is standard, as far as I'm aware:

```
ap.add_argument('--version', action='version',
                version='%(prog)s, version {version}'.format(version=versionParsed))
```